# How to fix if operation is not defined in the WSDL using php nusoap

Tags: linux, php, web-services

I am currently working on a project that uses web service **PHP Nusoap**. I implement it at first in the local computer and it is already working perfectly fine, it can insert already in the database.Since, we are also deploying our project in the production server **(Linux RHEL 4)** so we also need to include the web service. In implementing this in the production server, we got this error :

> Operation '' is not defined in the WSDL for this service Here is the
>   full details :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
 xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    <faultcode xsi:type="xsd:string">SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
    <faultactor xsi:type="xsd:string"></faultactor>
    <faultstring xsi:type="xsd:string">Operation &apos;&apos; is not defined in the WSDL for this service
    </faultstring>
    <detail xsi:type="xsd:string"></detail>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
```

HERE IS THE CODE :

**client.php**

```
<?php
    require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

    $file_name = $data['file_name'];
    $location = $data['location'];

    $client = new nusoap_client('http://servername:port/WebService/server.php?wsdl', true);

    if ($SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $err = $client->getError();

        if ($err) {
            echo "<h2> Constructor error </h2><pre>" . $err. "</pre>" ;
            echo "<h2> Debug </h2><pre>" . htmlspecialchars($client->getdebug(),        ENT_QUOTES) . "</pre>" ;
            exit();
        }

        $datas = array (
            'file_name' => $file_name,
            'location'   => $location
        );

        $result = $client->call('InsertData', $datas);

        if ($client->fault) {
            echo "<h2> Fault (Expect - The request contains an invalid SOAP Body)</h2> <pre>" ;
            print_r ($result);
            echo "</pre>";
        } else {
            $err = $client->getError ();
            if ($err) {
                echo "<h2> Error </h2><pre>" . $err.  "</pre>";
            } else {
                print_r ($result);
            }
        }
    } else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
        echo "Method is not POST " ;
    }

?>
```

**server.php**

```
<?php 
require_once('lib.nusoap');

$server = new soap_server();
$server->configureWSDL('Database Sample Insertion', 'urn:Insert');
$server->soap_defenconding = 'UTF-8' ;

$server->register('InsertData', 
    array (
        'file_name'  => 'xsd:file_name',
        'location'    => 'xsd:location'
    ),
    array ('return' => 'xsd:string'),
    'urn:Insert',
    'urn:Insertwsdl#InsertDate',
    'rpc',
    'literal'
);

function InsertData ($file_name, $location) {
    $db_host = 'localhost';
    $db_username = 'username';
    $db_password = '' ;
    $db_name = 'sample' ;

    $conn = new mysqli ($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        trigger_error('Database connection failed : ' .$conn->connect_error , E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO transaction (`filename`, `location`) VALUES ('$file_name', '$location')";

    $query = $conn->query($sql);

}

    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '' ;
    $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);


?>
```

what does this problem means and how can we solve this? Or how to setup the web service PHP Nusoap in the production server? Any ideas/suggestions is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: do you have any idea on how should I solve this? need help

Answer (score 1):

I'v had the same problem when PHP/Apache version changed at my server. Im my case the problem was located inside nusoap library function: `parse_http_headers()`

There is a function used to get all HTTP headers `getallheaders()` and it seems not getting all headers as it should. There were no `Content-Type` which is required for nusoap to parse request (ex. `text/xml`).

Fortunately nusoap checks if function `getallheaders()` exists and if not it uses `$_SERVER` array to parse headers.

Finally the one thing I had to do was to change one line of code inside nusoap.php file to disable this function:

```
if (function_exists('getallheaders')){ ...
```

to this one:

```
if (0 && function_exists('getallheaders')){ ...
```

Hope this help others!